# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'CuisineList'. Remove one definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, datasource

I have tried a few suggestions that I've found on Google and Stack Overflow, but they are not working.

Here is the dropdownlist control that my data is bound to -- note that it does not have a value for either DataSouce or DataSourceID

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CuisineList" runat="server" Width="100" 
     onselectedindexchanged="CuisineList_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

here is the code behind that binds the data to the dropdownlist control:

```
BLgetMasterData obj = new BLgetMasterData();
var cusineList = obj.getCuisines();
CuisineList.DataSourceID = null; 
CuisineList.DataSource = cusineList;
CuisineList.DataBind();
CuisineList.Items.Insert(0, "Any");
CuisineList.SelectedValue = "Any";
```

Comment: Don't think this is causing your problem but why do you have this line? `CuisineList.DataSourceID = null;`

Comment: That was one of the suggestions I found on stack overflow

Comment: I'd suggest you to triple check that there is no other code setting `DataSourceID`, error is quite clear and can't be wrong

Comment: I performed a 'find' in my project and there is no reference to datasourceid

Answer (score 0):

`CuisineList.DataBind();` will populate your list with data with the data source.
Just as you have inserted extra items into the list, you can remove them too.

```
CuisineList.Items.Remove("Item");
CuisineList.Items.RemoveAt(1);
CuisineList.Items.Remove(someOtherList.SelectedItem);
```

Refer: [dropdownlist items remove method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhez99sc)

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the question I posed.

Comment: Your questions states "Remove one definition". If you are not asking how to remove an item from the list, what are you asking?

Comment: Hi ... I'm not trying to remove an item from a collection, I'm trying to set to null a property somethow set on the collection.  I guess I didn't make myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

I were facing same problem even I checked into property & code behind page I did not use DataSourceID. I found its giving error because of Data Base Authentication. Please check your database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are giving two data source may be at different location.
Go to your aspx Design file and remove the DataSourceId attribute from DropDownList field.